# How to wait for multiple remote processes (via ssh) to finish?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, distributed, wait

My situation is that I have a number of processes that are supposed to start (more or less) at the same time in different remote hosts. A master script, which spawns all remote processes, should wait for all of them to finish, to only then proceed to the next distributed execution. The way I've tried this so far (with no success on Ubuntu Server 12.04, /bin/sh pointing to /bin/bash) was:

```
#!/bin/bash

for run_input in run1.data run2.data ; do
   for i in `seq 0 10` ; do
      ssh node$i "/path/to/bin $run_input /path/to/node$i.config" &
   done
   wait
done
```

So, what's wrong with the above approach?

EDIT:

Note that the command is different for each remote host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just answering my own question, there is nothing wrong with the way I was doing it (although some might recommend pssh or something similar to be used instead). The way I suggested in the question, a temporary ssh session is created with the remote host, for each command sent. This ssh session remains running on the background and, by simply calling `wait`, the script should pause until all background child processes are finished - in this case, the ssh sessions.

What I was doing wrong was that I was piping a file into a while loop, like:

```
cat file.txt | while read line ; do
    ssh node "do_something_with $line" &
done
wait
```

The problem with the above is that, when piping into a while loop, a sub-shell is created, so the remote ssh sessions created were not children of this script, but of the sub-shell. Therefore, calling `wait` had no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

For running parallel ssh at the same time, I recommend using [pssh](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/)

Doc is there : http://www.theether.org/pssh/docs/0.2.3/pssh-HOWTO.html

Then :

```
pssh -h /PATH/TO/FILE/WITH/HOSTS command
```

Comment: Good, so how do you send different commands to different destinations?

Comment: You should fill the `/PATH/TO/FILE/WITH/HOSTS` file with hosts on each lines; then `pssh -h file command1; command2; ...`